# How to check invariance using scalar products induced by standard norm?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, inner-products, invariance

At my university, we were to solve this exercise during representation theory lectures.

We consider the space $E$ of traceless Hermitian matrices as a real vector space of dimension 3:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2 + ix_3\\x_2 − ix_3&−x_1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Show that the scalar product induced by the ’standard’ norm on $E$ is $P$-invariant, where

$$\begin{align}
P: SU_2&\to {\rm Aut}_R(E),\\
P(A) \to X&\mapsto AXA^{−1}.
\end{align}$$

My progress:

Take the scalar product on E, which is induced by a standard norm on E. Then check the definition of invariance, which is $\langle f(u), f(v)\rangle_E$ is equal to $\langle u,v\rangle_{SU_2}$ for any $u,v \in E$ and $f: SU_2 \to {\rm Aut}_\mathbb{R}(E) $. My guess is that the scalar product on $E$ the square root of sum of squares of vector coordinates. However, I don´t know how to check the equality of these scalar product, or where I am possibly wrong.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the scalar product on a set of square complex matrices is
introduced by the rule $(x,y)=\operatorname{tr}(xy^*)$, where $y^*=\bar y^T$
(as you can see no square roots).

Here $\operatorname{tr}(x)$ is the trace of matrix $x$,
i.e. the sum of elements of the main diagonal of $x$.
In the case of Hermitian matrices, the formula is simplified by
$(x,y)=\operatorname{tr}(xy)$.
So
$$
(f(x),f(y))=\operatorname{tr}(f(x)f(y))=\operatorname{tr}(axa^{-1}aya^{-1})
$$

$$
=\operatorname{tr}(axya^{-1})=\operatorname{tr}(xy)=(x,y).
$$